# How to calculate Calculate max end date inTask Recurrence

Tags: apex, formula, tasks

I am creating a custom VF page for tasks. In the page one Recurrence field option is available. In this we can give the task a start date and end date. In the end date we can calculate max end date, but I am not sure how to do this in my Custom VF page.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  I really think you need to provide a bit more detail as I am unsure exactly what you are asking.....

Comment: @sfdc_ninja i am creating custom VF page for task in the page one Recurence field option is available.in this we can give task startdate and end date. in the end date we can calculate max end date but i am not sure how to do this in my Custom VF page

Comment: I believe you copied the text of the above question. You need to: State what you mean by reoccurrence, confirm that you are using a Task, Define why you need the End Date and what parameters drive the Max End Date calc. Also, some sample code showing what you have tried would be very useful.

Comment: @CaspNZ i am creating Custom vf page for task so i have to give all ame functionality as standard page. now in standard page when give task recureence there is one max end date limit .this limit is calculated basis of what frequency and other option you choose now i don't know how to implement  his on my custom VF page